# Insert into 2 tables with single insert statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-insert

In MSSQL inserting into 2 tables is possible with single  insert statement like below(with OUTPUT clause):

```
    insert into Table1(ID1 , Col1)
    OUTPUT inserted.ID1, Inserted.Col1
    into Table2
    values(1,'Col'), (2,'Col2');
```

Do we have any alternative for this in postgresql? I have tried with below already which is working for me now:

```
     with cte as 
    (insert into Table1(ID1 , Col1)
    values(1,'Col'), (2,'Col2')
    returning *)
    insert into Table2 select * from cte ;
```

Please let me know if we have any other alternative. I know about trigger also, but I don't want to use it here.

Comment: Your method is fine, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: Using a data modifying CTE is the right solution.

Comment: I  just wanted to check out if there is any other option/method available to so the same. So that, I'll not need to use cte each time.